# Exercise from Kaplansky - Commutative Rings (1.1.3)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Exercise 3 in section 1-1:

Let $P$ be a finitely generated prime ideal with annihilator 0.  Prove that the annihilator of the module $P/P^2$ is $P$.  (Hint: If $p_1,\cdots,p_n$ generate $P$ and $x$ annihilates $P/P^2$, then $xp_i = \sum a_{ij}p_j$ for $a_{ij} \in P$.  Take determinant.)

What I don't understand:  I understand the problem except for the determinant part.  From $xp_i = \sum a_{ij}p_j$, I rearrange to obtain: $$xp_i - \sum a_{ij}p_j = 0.$$  This will give me a matrix which I can take the determinant of.  The next section in the book has a similar proof for Theorem 12, but I don't quite understand the very end of the proof since Kaplansky does not give the details.

Why does the determinant annihilate $p_1,\cdots,p_n$?  I see if the determinant does this, then the determinant must be 0 given our hypothesis.  Additionally, I don't quite see how the determinant being 0 helps.  I was thinking it had to do with eigenvalues somehow, but wasn't sure.  Any explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: Let $A$ be the $n\times n$-matrix whose $\left(i,j\right)$-th entry is $a_{ij}$. Then, $A \left(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n\right)^T = \left(xp_1,xp_2,\ldots,xp_n\right)^T$, so that $\left(A-xI_n\right) \left(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n\right)^T = 0$. Therefore, $\det \left(A-xI_n\right) \left(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n\right)^T = 0$ (since $\det M = \operatorname{adj} M \cdot M$ for any square matrix $M$, in particular also for $M = A-xI_n$). Thus, $\det \left(A-xI_n\right)$ annihilates each of $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$.

Comment: Oh okay!  That makes sense now.  I did not think about using the adjugate.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that all but one of the terms of the determinant is trivially in $P$, and the last one is $x^n$.  So if the determinant vanishes, we have $x\in P$.

As for why the determinant annihilates $p_1, \ldots , p_n$, the only way I know of to show this is using the adjugate: there is a matrix $A^{adj}$ such that $A^{adj} A = (\det A)I_n$, and it follows that if a vector is annihilated by $A$, any component is annihilated by the determinant.

Comment: Okay!  That all makes sense.  Thank you!  I was stuck on this for a while!  There's several other exercises and proof of theorems that used this trick so that helps.  Thanks!